# NFS Drives Unmount Seemingly Randomly

Tags: performance, nfs, unmount

I have an ubuntu server for media streaming at home. Everything seems to work ok. I can read and write from my mac laptop and get pretty good speeds. The drives are 2 USB external boxes (4 x 4tb and 2 x 2tb) and one SATA 2tb internal SSD.

The problem: I have found that the drives in the 4 x 4tb box will unmount after some writes. Sometimes the writes won't complete.

Any help boosting my NFS stability/performance please???

Here's one of my export lines (they're all the same):
`/mnt/Share/Peebles      192.168.0.1/24(rw,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)`

Comment: Does the 4x4TB USB drive only disconnect when you are doing writes across NFS or even when you are trying to write to it directly from the server it is connected to?

Comment: Only during NFS writes, server side I've never seen a problem. I've copied each drive once in their entireties when I reformatted them to ext4 (so super stable).